# How to host multiple websites on one server...with one public IP...with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am a new to the server world, and I need some assistance setting one up.

**Here is my question: How can I host multiple websites on one server...with one public IP address...with Apache, without having to have registered domain names for each website?**

I would like to be able to type in my public IP address from anywhere...and have the ability to view any particular website on the server. Perhaps...by typing this into a browser address bar for one website--*http://xx.xxx.xxx.x:80*, and this into the address bar for another website--*http://xx.xxx.xxx.x:81*.

I'm not sure how to do this; I haven't been able to find tutorials or guides for this goal.

I am using Apache 2 on Ubuntu Server 12.04. My server computer is going through a home router (is using the router's public IP address).

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is it possible not to find this? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/ Do you consider your problem (not finding the most basic document) "professional IT"? Only that is on-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Unfortunately, your question is probably going to be closed, because it relates to computers in a home setting, and hence is offtopic.  Please check out the [faq]

Comment: Not to mention, domain names are quite cheap. If you're a developer, you should already have one. If not, go get one.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `<VirtualHost ipaddr:port>` line in the Apache config files. For ubuntu, I believe there is a directory for these in `/etc/apache2/vhost.config/` or something like that. You'd use a VirtualHost section for each of your sites, but on a different port for each.